# Injection of autowired dependencies failed Error creating bean with name Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

i am creating the spring boot project along with spring security.while running the project i got the error was
complete error i attached below please anyone help us to solve this below error

complete stack trace i attached below please check

```
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:498) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:950) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:738) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:440) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at com.example.springjwt.SpringJwtApplication.main(SpringJwtApplication.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void setServletContext(jakarta.servlet.ServletContext)' of interface org.springframework.web.context.ServletContextAware.
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ServletContextAwareProcessor.java:108) ~[spring-web-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:419) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:410) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.postProcess(AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.java:65) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.9.jar:5.7.9]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:152) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.9.jar:5.7.9]
    at
```

**WebSecurityConfiguration**

```
   @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAunthenticationEntryPoint() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate","/user/register-new-user").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpHeaders.ALLOW).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                // reference here the method of the @Bean
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAunthenticationEntryPoint())
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


}
```

**JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint**

```
    public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
        @Override
        public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                             AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
    
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**NEW ANSWER**

Since now we have the complete stacktrace, it appears you're using `spring-security-config-5.7.9` alonside `spring-6`.

The 5.7 branch of Spring Security is base on Spring 5, so you won't be able to make it work like this.

Moreover the `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated in the same branch, see javadoc for more informations but here's an extract :

> Deprecated. Use a org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain Bean to configure HttpSecurity or a WebSecurityCustomizer Bean to configure WebSecurity.

```java
     @Bean
     public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http
             .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) ->
                 authz.anyRequest().authenticated()
             );
             // ...
         return http.build();
     }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer(WebSecurity web) {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }
```

> See the Spring Security without WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter for more details.

First align your Spring / SpringSecurity versions, and then use the new configuration as explained in the javadoc to customize your SpringSecurity context

**INITIAL ANSWER**

Is the `JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint` class well-scanned by Spring ?

If not, it won't be auto-created by SpringBoot.

Two solutions for you :

1. Add the `scanBasePackageClasses` attribute to your `@SpringBootApplication`

Example :

```java
@SpringBootApplication(
        scanBasePackageClasses = { JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint.class }
)
```

It will then load any classes that are under the `JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint` class' package.

2. Remove the `@Component` annotation and declare the `JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint` as `@Bean` in your `WebSecurityConfiguration` configuration class. Then use it in your configure method.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAunthenticationEntryPoint() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate","/user/register-new-user").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpHeaders.ALLOW).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                // reference here the method of the @Bean
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAunthenticationEntryPoint())
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

// ...
}
```

Comment: i have changed what you told above but still getting the same error. please check my update code

Comment: Thanks, could you share more of the stacktrace please ? Maybe `jwtAunthenticationEntryPoint` wasn't the error. You should have the name of the non-injected bean somewhere in the error message

Comment: i have updated the full stack trace please check it

Comment: Thanks again, will update my answer :)

Comment: ok thanks i am waiting

Comment: Done (above my initial answer :))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256112/discussion-between-gowry-kanth-and-laurent-schoelens).